# other better ways

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> Are there any other better ways to deal with the matter.

Can I add an adjective between other and a
noun like the above sentence? I hardly saw any noun phrase employing this usage "other + adj. + noun".

Comment: Are there any other hot potatoes?  Are there any other green houses in the neighborhood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to address the example sentence.

> Is there any other better ways to deal with the matter.

In this sentence, "other better" is redundant.  It should be "Are there any better ways to deal with the matter?"  Better is a comparative adjective, and therefore already implies 'other.'

But, as for your question in general:

> Can I add an adjective between other and a noun like the above
>   sentence?

Yes, you can use the structure: other + adj. + noun
You just shouldn't use comparative adjectives like better, happier, smarter, etc.

In fact, the sentence above could be easily changed to fit this structure. Just change the comparative adjective 'better' to the regular adjective 'good.'

> Are there any other good ways to deal with the matter?

Here are some other examples

> Are there any other quiet neighborhoods we can look at?
>
> Are there any other happy people left in this world?
>
> Are there any other red apples left?
>
> Do you like any other sweet foods?
>
> Do you have any other good suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The structure [[any] [other]] [adjective] [noun] is certainly available.

> Are there any other sensible options?
>
> Any other small car will be acceptable.

The adjective used here is in the classifier role, and carries the function of specifying a more select set; the adjective modifies the noun cohesively:

> Are there any other options that are sensible ones?
>
> Any other member of the 'small car' class will be acceptable.

It is unusual, though not impossible, to use a comparative adjective as a classifier:

> "A, B and C are better ways."
>
> ... "Are there any more/other 'better ways' before we choose one of John's
>   suggestions?"

(Note that we have a set of at least 3 'better ways', a subset of all possible ways.)

.........

Another correct usage is as a parenthetical (as an afterthought or climactic):

> There are other ... better ... ways.

Though in this case, the determiner 'other' and the adjective 'better' are independent (There are other ways. And they are better.)